# How do I present progress in an Angular bar chart?

Tags: angular, chart.js

anybody an idea how I can achieve something like this here?
[image]

These are two bar charts where each has a greyed out area which is its own 100% or max value. This is just a mockup, so we can just go off and assume we're working with one bar.
I'm using angular chartjs but wasn't able to plot something like in the mockup.

I tried

```js
  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            max: 75,
            callback: function (value) {
              return ((value / 75) * 100).toFixed(0);
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [{ data: [50] }];
```

This however doesn't result in anything usable.
Am I even on the right track if all I want is a bar as depicted in my mockup? Not even sure if using the chartjs library here is the right choice.
Really, what I want to show is: "There is a maximum number of 75 (that's the grey area), but so far I've got 50 (that's the colourful area)"

Comment: Maybe you could use the `progress` element, and then style that?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're simply building a 'single percentage bar' then this is simple enough to achieve in Chart.js. Set the scale as `max: 100` and `min: 0` and then only draw the blue bar:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: '#249DD6',
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      data: [25]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          max: 100,
          min: 0
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #D6D7D9
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="25px"></canvas>
```

Comment: @DavidO'Brien Did this answer your question?